# React update state with button click using useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can anyone explain to me what the "right" way is to do the below problem. I have this simple page which has event-data. Initially this is data from the last week, but there is a button on the page which sets data to all. I use useEffect() to loadData() with setting all=false initially. When I click the button, I want to update all to true and data to all data.

The below code works, but it is somewhat weird, because I first have to get the data for !all and after that I set all=true, but then it rerenders again.

Is there a nice way to do this? I tried putting the "onClick" code the other way around, so: setAll(!all);loadData(all), but this doesnt work, because the state isnt immediately updated.

Any help/tips would be great!!

```
 const Events = ({auth}) => {


const [data, setEventData] = useState([])
const [all, setAll] = useState(false)

const loadData = async (givenScope) => {
    const scope = (givenScope ? '' : '?scope=last_week')
    const eventdata = await makeAPICall('/api/events' + scope, 'GET', null, await auth.getAccessToken())
    setEventData(eventdata);
}

useEffect(() => {
    loadData(all);
}, [])

const columns = [{
    Header: 'Datum/tijd',
    accessor: 'datetime',
    Cell: props => <Moment date={props.value} tz="Europe/Amsterdam" format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"/>
}, {
    Header: 'Event',
    accessor: 'value',
}]        

return <div><Button onClick={() => {loadData(!all);setAll(!all)}}>{all ? 'Last week' : 'All'}</Button> <DefaultTable data={data} columns={columns} loading={data.length > 0 ? false : true} /></div>

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A relatively simple way to handle the above code would be pass `all` as value to dependency array of `useEffect` so that you don't worry about `loadData` being executed after state update

```
const Events = ({auth}) => {

    const [data, setEventData] = useState([])
    const [all, setAll] = useState(false)

    const loadData = async (givenScope) => {
        const scope = (givenScope ? '' : '?scope=last_week')
        const eventdata = await makeAPICall('/api/events' + scope, 'GET', null, await auth.getAccessToken())
        setEventData(eventdata);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData(all);
    }, [all])

    const columns = [{
        Header: 'Datum/tijd',
        accessor: 'datetime',
        Cell: props => <Moment date={props.value} tz="Europe/Amsterdam" format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"/>
    }, {
        Header: 'Event',
        accessor: 'value',
    }]        

    return <div><Button onClick={() => {setAll(all => !all)}}>{all ? 'Last week' : 'All'}</Button> <DefaultTable data={data} columns={columns} loading={data.length > 0 ? false : true} /></div>

}
```

And in any case your code will render twice since data is available asynchronously. To improve user experience you can show a loader while the data is being fetched.

Comment: I am questioning myself why I didnt come up with this. Thank you. Is this also the way you would do it? I love beautiful code but in react I cant seem to find my way to beautiful code.

Comment: I would definitely do it in the above manner. Also good code comes with practise and I am sure you will become better at it

Comment: Thanks. I cant upvote your answer because my reputation is still too low :) for the record: GUYS THIS IS THE ANSWER :)

Comment: No issues, you can however still mark the answer as accepted using greentick which occurs below the votes

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this on your button's `onClick`:

```
<Button 
  onClick={ () => {
    setAll((prevState) => {
      loadData(!prevState);    // This will load the data during the state update
      return !prevState;
    }
  }}
/>
```